# What cost basis do I report on the 1099?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1099, cost-basis, rsu

Let's say hypothetically $10,000 of RSU vested this past year.

My employer has listed $10,000 of RSU onto my W-2 in Box 14.

I elected sell-to-cover so now I'm left with ~$5,500 after the sell-to-cover.

The 1099-B imported from E-Trade says I had a transaction with sell price ~$4,500.

What cost basis should I report for that transaction? Is it $10,000? Or $5,500?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't fill out a 1099, your employer would or possibly whoever manages the stock account.

> The 1099-B imported from E-Trade says I had a transaction with sell price ~$4,500.

Yes.  You sold ~$4500 of stock to pay income taxes.  Both the cost basis and the sale price would probably be ~$4500, so no capital gain.  This is because you received and sold the stock at the same time.  If they waited a little, you could have had a small gain or loss.

The remainder of the stock has a cost basis of ~$5500.

There are at least two transactions here.

1. Receive ~$10,000 worth of stock.  Cost basis of ~$10,000.
2. Sell ~$4500 worth of stock.  Cost basis of ~$4500.

In the future you may sell the remaining stock.  It has a cost basis of ~$5500.  Sale price of course unknown until then.  You may break that into different pieces.  So you might sell $500 of cost basis for $1000 with a ~$500 capital gain.  Then later sell the remainder for $15,000 for a capital gain of ~$10,000.